# C#/WPF Bind to Earliest Date in Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've got an `ObservableCollection<LegEventItems>` that holds items. I have a timeline in which I need to get the Earliest date in this collection for the *period start* property. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

I'd like to do this all in xaml (with the exception of creating properties or converters) if possible. I've tried to create a converter and use it like such:

`{Binding Source={x:Static cs:CurrentData.LegEventItems}, Converter={StaticResource earliestDateCnv}}`

The issue is the values don't get updated in the converter. It gets called once when the timeline first renders, however when more items get put/removed from the observable collection, it doesn't update.

I've incorporated `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the LegEventItems already. Any idea?

Comment: The Binding isn't triggered when items are added to or removed from the collection, because the collection object isn't replaced. You should add an `EarliestLegEventItem` property to your view model.

Comment: @Clemens I'm not using MVVM. Also, what would update a property like that when an item gets removed/added? It would constantly have to be updated because I have items getting added from different places all over.

Comment: Don't use a static property - I seriously doubt they are part of the INotifyPropertyChanged mechanism since interfaces are for instance stuff.

Comment: Since WPF there is a mechanism to notify about static property changes, but the Binding expression would look differently, i.e. `{Binding Path=(cs:CurrentData.LegEventItems)}`. However, even then there is no actual change of the LegEventItems property (and hence no notification) when elements are added or removed.

Comment: @hoodaticus I'm in a situation where the static property is necessary. The items are getting updated fine, I just need to get the EarliestDate of that observable collection and have that constantly update based on the current items in the collection.

Comment: "Since WPF" should read "Since WPF 4.5".

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution. I'm subscribing to the `CollectionChanged` event in my user control class (with the timeline). When that fires, I update the **periodStart** and **periodEnd** properties. Wish I was able to  use pure xaml like I had said in the question, however this is a solution I'm fine with rolling with.